# .yml file and Symfony2/Doctrine2 - Escaping special char in password

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a MySQL password with special chars "%" and "$". How can I use it with Symfony2/Doctrine2 and .yml files?

I try:
"pa%s$s"
'pa%s$s'
pa%s$s
and it didn't work.

Comment: You can post your comment as an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:
Escaping: "%" char
Use: "%%"

Example:
"pa%s%s"
should be: "pa%%s%%s"